# ConcurrentModificationException with very limited iterations

Tags: java, generic-lambda

I am trying to learn caching and I tried this:

```
public static <T, U, R> BiFunction<T, U, R> cached(BiFunction<T, U, R> bifunc) {
    Cache<Pair<T,U>, R> cache = new Cache<Pair<T,U>, R>(DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE);
    
    System.out.println("Cache Size: "+cache.size());
    
    return (t, u) -> {
        Pair<T,U> pairKey = new Pair<T,U>(t,u);
        
        Function<Pair<T,U>, R> something = input -> {
            return bifunc.apply(input.get_first(), input.get_second());
        };
        
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(pairKey, something);
    };
}
```

For my cache and this to get the actual result:

```
BiFunction<BigInteger, BiFunction, BigInteger> fibHelper = cached((n, f) -> {
        if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.TWO) <= 0) return BigInteger.ONE;
        
        return ((BigInteger) (f.apply(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), f)))
                .add((BigInteger)f.apply(n.subtract(BigInteger.TWO), f));
    });
    
Function<BigInteger, BigInteger> fib = (n) -> fibHelper.apply(n,fibHelper);

BigInteger large = fib.apply(BigInteger.valueOf(3L));
```

I've tested it to run with big numbers and I'm getting a ConcurrentModificationException, so I tried to run with low numbers, when I tried to run with input 0 - 2 it works fine, but once I get to 3 and onwards I get a ConcurrentModificationException. I'm using a LinkedHashMap by the way.

I'm fairly new to this, any help?

Comment: Nothing in this snippet that would suggest it; the problem is probably in your `Cache` class. Add that to the question, that'd help.

Answer (score 0):

Your data structures are not Thread-Safe.

**ConcurrentModificationException** is usually received when **two threads are using/overriding the same object** (usually data structures), **or when an object is changed during iterating it** *(thanks Thomas Kläger).*

I didn't understand what do you mean by

> I'm using a LinkedHashMap

In which context?

BTW, LinkedHashMap is not concurrent-safe.
If you want concurrent-safe data structures, you should use java.util.Concurrent package.

As rzwitserloot said, please provide full implementation or clearer explanation.

Comment: You don't need multiple threads for `ConcurrentModificationException` to occur. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/223918/5646962 for an example

Comment: You are right, I meant the common case for ConcurrentModificationException is un-safe thread usage. There's also this iteration-during-removal thing. Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it seems that computeIfAbsent can be replaced by standard if/else which works perfectly.

```
public static <T, U, R> BiFunction<T, U, R> cached(BiFunction<T, U, R> bifunc) {
    Cache<Pair<T,U>, R> cache = new Cache<Pair<T,U>, R>(DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE);
    
    return (t, u) -> {
        Pair<T,U> pairKey = new Pair<T,U>(t,u);
        
        Function<Pair<T,U>, R> something = input -> {
            return bifunc.apply(input.get_first(), input.get_second());
        };
        
        if (!cache.containsKey(pairKey)) {
            R result = something.apply(pairKey);
            cache.put(pairKey, result);
            
            return result;
        } else {
            return cache.get(pairKey);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the mapping function that you supply to `computeIfAbsent()`.

The JavaDoc for [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) states:

> The mapping function should not modify this map during computation.
>
> This method will, on a best-effort basis, throw a ConcurrentModificationException if it is detected that the mapping function modifies this map during computation.

When computing `fib(3)` (or anything larger) it calls `computeIfAbsent(..3..)` which recursively calls `computeIfAbsent(..2..)` which modifies the map during the computation.

The solution to the problem is what you found out yourself: don't use `computeIfAbsent()` for recursive algorithms.